# Окно выбора аккаунта

Tags: java, android

Для выбора аккаунта использую данный код, но если моих аккаунтов в системе ещё нет должно показаться окно добавления аккаунта. Так вот я сначала вижу маленько окошко где нет аккаунтов, а уже где-то через секунду вижу окно добавления аккаунта. Как это можно избежать? Если нет аккаунта - сразу окно добавления, есть аккаунт - окно выбора.

```
            Intent intent;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{ACCOUNT_TYPE}, "Выберите аккаунт", ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, null);
            } else {
                intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{ACCOUNT_TYPE}, false, null, null, null, null);
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Так вы же не проверяете массив аккаунтов, сделайте проверку, есть ли аккаунт. И проверять аккаунты не всей системы, а конкретного приложения

Answer (score 2):

Это пример для всех аккаунтов на device, при запросе используйте ваш список, при вызове намерения аналогично.

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
    if (accounts.length == 0){
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, null , true, null, null, null, null);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Если на телефоне нет аккаунтов вызовется системное окно для добавления.